# Checking for duplicates before updating a field

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing Android application that sends `HTTP requests` to a server using `php and mysql`.

The user has to fill in two fields. let's say A and B these will be added to two columns  of a table (col A and col B. However, I want to add the contents of A to B after that. it works fine.

I am having a problem in checking the duplicates of A in B. The result i want is A as the user enters and B of the content of A+B with no duplicates.

This is what i am using

```
$A = $_POST['A'];
$last_inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();
$updateTable = mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET B=IFNULL(CONCAT(B, '$A'), '$A')WHERE    _id='$last_inserted_id'");
```

To make it clearer, B contains only words not a sentence, however, A is a sentence.

so I stemmed the sentence A .. for example A="I want to learn programming" -$A= "learn programming".

So if B is programming .. the final result must be learn and programming only . Now I'm getting learn programming learn.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP instead of MySQL to handle this, before storing in database?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_query` interface, it's deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is a good alternative, and has the advantage of fixing your [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) by providing a simple, reliable method for [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: thanks @tadman i will change to the new structure right now

Answer (score 1):

If this record was just inserted, you probably could've put that data in there in the first place. If this is a subsequent request, then `mysql_insert_id()` cannot be trusted, as other records might've been inserted.

Is there anything that precludes you from putting the data in there in the first place?

If you want a method to append to an existing field, you could simplify this by defaulting `B` to be an empty string, making the `IFNULL` check on your `CONCAT` call redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve it using php code I save the results into two arrays and took the difference between them and then merge with the original B values. it's working for now.